# Prevent unwanted commit from re-entering git history when doing pulls

Tags: git

I work in a distributed team and use a central git repository to collaborate on certain tasks (not code).  We have several team members who are light git users, comfortable with push, pull, add commit, status, etc; but not the more advanced concepts.

Recently a very large commit was added accidentally which we wanted to remove.  I did a `rebase -i`, removed the errant commit (which had over 1gb of binary files), and `push -f`'d the changes back.

However, every time a member did a git pull in the future, it merely merges their local changes back into my changes!  How do I force them to discard their local commit history and use mine.  My solution was to email them all and do:

```
git fetch
git checkout origin/master
git branch -f master origin/master
git checkout master
```

Is there any better way?

Comment: It's possible that you could do the same using fewer commands, but I don't think there's a better way in principle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an [`update` hook](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks) that verifies the offending commit is not in the history that they are attempting to push, and rejects the push if it does contain the commit in question.

Answer (score 1):

```
git revert commit_hash
```

This should revert the changes that that commit introduced and create a new commit with those changes removed.This is preferable as it shows the history of the changes being introduced, then the changes being removed, instead of trying to pretend like it never happened.

Comment: I'm going to guess that the binary files should have never ended up in the repo in the first place.

Comment: This would be the answer in many situations - but not when as Mike and the OP say, the commit simply can't exist in the repo. Everyone has to rewrite their history.