# Example of a git hook that prevents old history falsely restored?

Tags: git, github, githooks

In this link
[Prevent unwanted commit from re-entering git history when doing pulls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6754937/prevent-unwanted-commit-from-re-entering-git-history-when-doing-pulls)

The accepted answer describes generally the solution of a git pre-push hook that accomplishes the reporter's request.

But I cannot find any good example.

Question 1: are these old commits visible in a PR?
Question 2: A git hook only checks only the new commits in PR, or also all the previous ones?

I have checked the refering link: https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks
but it's not clear how to prevent old commits reentering.

Answer (score -1):

Question 1: If you implement a pre-push hook, and catch commits from being pushed to the remote, no they will not be present in a GitHub PR.

Question 2: A git hook will not check any commits in a PR. A PR is not a git concept, it is a feature of GitHub.

Your best options for preventing certain commits from being merged into your main branch on the remote repository are 1 or more of the following:

1. Create a pre-push hook to deny pushes to the remote based on the commit SHAs being pushed
2. Create a pre-receive hook (if using GitHub Enterprise Server) to deny pushes containing a certain commit SHA
3. Create a [status check](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/collaborating-on-repositories-with-code-quality-features/about-status-checks) for pull requests on the repository to deny any PRs from being merged to the main branch if they contain a certain commit SHA